# How can I use gmail mobile without having to sync

Tags: samsung, sync, gmail, email

I have a school google account that does not allow sync.

I have just added it to my Android phone and set up gmail, however when I try and get onto the account it asks to sync.

As sync is disabled the sync button will not work. The 3 line setting button just displays Waiting for Sync.

How do I use GMAil on my phone?

I cannot install any other apps since the phone only has 200mb due to the fact that it is a cheap Samsung.

Comment: Does it work if you disable syncing gmail from your devices settings? Should be under accounts then select google. Next, select your account if multiple accounts are on the device. Then go down to gmail and un-tick the selector.